# Unserialize string incoming string

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have serialized array. It is serialized into string looking like:
`*field1_name*|*field1_value*;*field2_name*|*field2_value*;*field3_name*|*field3_value*` etc.
I need to get value of field 3.

At this moment i get it by:

```
explode("*|*", explode("*;*", serialized_array)[3])[1]
```

but i'm almost sure that there is better way to do this.
Is in php function that allows to turn it into associative array?

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: That's a custom serialization, there isn't a standard way to unserialize it.
Regardless of the method adopted, you have to create a single function to be called every time you need to extract data or better convert the serialized data into an array:
`$unserializedData = unserializer($serializedData); $wantedValue = $unserializedData['wantedKey'];`

Answer (score 0):

Very-very-very basic solution:

```php
function unserializer ($serializedData)
{
    $unserializedData = [];
    
    foreach (explode('*;*', trim ($serializedData, '*')) as $keyVal) {
       [$key, $val] = explode ('*|*', $keyVal);
       $unserializedData[$key] = $val;
    }
    
    return $unserializedData;
}

$ser = '*field1_name*|*field1_value*;*field2_name*|*field2_value*;*field3_name*|*field3_value*';
var_export (unserializer ($ser));
```

In the real world, errors may need to be handled

Answer (score -1):

If i understand Your idea step 1 should looks like:

```
$query_string = str_replace(["*;*", "*|*"], ["&", "="], $serialized_string);
```

All of "*", "|", ";" can be in field_value, so replace all of them isn't a good way.